# Symfony2: URL query string lost with login redirection

Tags: symfony, authentication, query-string

URL to the application with query string : http://myapp.fr/?param1=toto&param2=tata

**When not authenticated: the browser is redirected to http://myapp.fr/login and query string is lost.**

**Any idea to how preserve the query string during login challenge ?**

Note 1: it works fine when browser is already authenticated in application: query string can be read in controllers.

Note 2: there are few parameters so i can hard code them somewhere if needed.

Note 3: the URL is created by another application and i CANNOT change it to something more convenient to symfony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine with no parameters at all !

```
    form_login:
```

3 cases are OK:

- / => /login => /
- /login => /
- /?param1=toto => /login => /?param1=toto

Answer (score 0):

in security.yml
try to use

> use_referer : true

```
    login:
        pattern:  ^/(login)
        anonymous: true
        always_use_default_target_path : true
        default_target_path: /any-default-path
        use_referer : true
```

Comment: I added the user_referer : true attribute
And the problem is not solved.
Didn't see any change.

Comment: Symfony security is taking off the parameters. It understand that It intercepts the request and checks if you're logged in. Do you have public navigation or anonymusly navigation in your site or is It require to be logged in to access to every functionality?

Comment: No public, no anonymous navigation. Only logged to access functionality.